# Can't install openCV in macOS Sierra

Tags: python, opencv, macos-sierra

I tried to install openCV in macOS Sierra as given in the site:
[www.pyimagesearch.com](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/).
The code was build successfully but when I try to access the openCV this error shows up.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZL13pyopencv_fromIN2cv4MatxIdLi4ELi4EEEEP7_objectRKT_
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that worked for me was to first install anaconda:

https://conda.io/docs/installation.html

Then, make a downgrade of the python version and install opencv3:

```
conda install python=3.5
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

This worked as a charm for me.

EDIT

You can also install through pip using the following:

```
pip install opencv-python
```